# Python virtual method without crapping names

Tags: python, python-3.x

sample code what i am talking about

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 5
  def virtual__getX(self):
    return self.x
  def getY(self):
    return self.virtual__getX()+2

class B(A):
  def __init__(self):
    A.__init__(self)
  def virtual__getX(self):
    return 20

a=A()
b=B()

print(a.getY())
print(b.getY())
```

is there a way in python 3 to have real virtual method without this really bad name "virtual__getX" i need clear names "__getX"

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

7
22
```

if i remove virtual from name the result is

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

7
7
```

is there better way to write real virtual methods like in "normal language" like delphi

Comment: Wait, so you want to inherit from another class and don't have inheritance? What are you actually trying to achieve? It seems like you need to use properties. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

Comment: properties are usefull but not in this case, i need to have something like protected member, inheritance is important but from INSTANCE user should not call method, but question is  answered - problem was in double underscore which is used by python internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a virtual function named `__something`. Attributes starting with a double underscore are considered private, and python internally applies name-mangling to them.

You can, however, rename `virtual__getX` to `getX` and it'll work as you expect.

Comment: really amaizing that double underscore have some "strange" behavior here. Is there a way to leve underscore and still have possibility to do this - something like @property decorator?

Comment: @Livius You can add another 2 backslashes at the end: `__getX__`. Names like that are usually used by python's magic methods though, so it isn't considered good practice. I don't know why you want to have getter functions, but in python we usually use properties instead. (Named `x`, not `getX` or anything else.)

Comment: i prefix all methods that do much more then only read property value with "get" but for internal class usage i prefix method by __ to "say" users do not call it from instance - but i see that if i need inheritance of that method then there is no good way to do this in python. In delphi i simple write "; virtual" after method and name dose not metter

Comment: @Livius why not just use a single underscore: `_getX`

Comment: good point but now i'm worry if in python are more magic with single underscore?

Comment: @Livius No, a single underscore doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Livius No, single underscore has no magic. Double-underscore specifically does *name-mangling*.

Comment: @Livius that being said, you shouldn't use getters and setters in Python. You should use properties *and that only when you need them*. That is the beauty of Python.